# What should be whitelisted in a firewall to allow push-notifications?

Tags: android-10, firewall, push-notifications

I'm using a firewall (NoRoot) on (Samsung) Android (10) to try to harden it, but now, push-notifications aren't coming through. I'm trying to figure out which apps/services are responsible for that and what URLs/ports need to be whitelisted. I've seen several candidates that might be it:

- `System`
- A *different* `System`‽
- `System (Uninstalled)`
- `Google Play services/Google Services Framework`
- `AASAservice, Accessibility, … … …, Wallpapers, WlanTest` (very long list)
- `Hiya Service`

Most search results just mention [this page](https://support.google.com/work/android/answer/10513641) which doesn't specify the app/service that requires the URLs and ports listed. Likewise, this [answer](https://serverfault.com/a/569621/14019) (which is outdated since GCM is deprecated) also doesn't specify *which service* to whitelist. And [this page](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/connections-mobile?topic=mobile-configuring-push-notifications) outright recommends just allowing everything which defeats the whole point to a firewall.

Comment: I would like to add this answer as it contains a push related server https://android.stackexchange.com/a/233287/2241 But I fear the answer is outdated as I can not remember having seen mtalk server the last time I checked Google traffic using a proxy.

Comment: Related: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#messaging-ports-and-your-firewall

Comment: (I've been trying to do some tests to try to narrow it down, but without an easy and reliable way to induce notifications, it's been slow going. So far, it's looking like it might be the `Google Play services, Google Services Framework` app/service that needs to be whitelisted, though the catchall `AAAServer…WlanTest` service doesn't seem to want to shut up with its requests.  Also, I have `Samsung Push Service` whitelisted, but I can't imagine that's required for everything since not all Android is Samsung.